# "in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'." In node APP

Tags: node.js, express, iframe, cross-domain

I have a node app, which run on domain and subdomain.

Example:

**abc.com -> main server**

**abc.com/admin -> admin panel**

**a.abc.com -> a user portal**

**b.abc.com -> another user portal**

Now I need to "**a.abc.com**" in "**abc.com**" inside the iframe. If I use

> a.abc.com/admin

which also open admin portal then I am able to see

> a.abc.com

in Iframe but If I login with

> abc.com/admin

and try **a.abc.com** or **b.abc.com** in iframe it gives error

> Refused to display 'http://a.abc.com' in a frame because it set
> 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

How to allow this? I am using node / express.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used helmet module

```
app.use(helmet())
```

which set origin to sameorigin so it allow on only for same origin

Changed it to

```
app.use(helmet({
  frameguard: false
}));
```

Now it works :)